# Aditivity of a linear mapping question.

Tags: linear-algebra

We have a linear mapping $A: (x,y) \to (x, e^y)$.

When proving additivity I have a doubt. We have to prove that $A(\vec{x}+\vec{y}) = A\vec{x} + A\vec{y}$. Let $\vec{x} = (x,y)$ and $\vec{y} = (x',y')$.

We go like this: $A(\vec{x}+\vec{y})$ = $A((x,y) + (x',y'))$ = $A(x + x', y + y')$ = $(x + x', e^y + e^{y'})$ = $(x, e^y) + (x', e^{y'})$ = $A\vec{x} + A\vec{y}$.

My question: When we evaluate this $A(x + x', y + y')$ do we take component by component, $x \to x$ and $x' \to x'$, so $x + x' \to x + x'$ or we take the  whole first component in this case $x + x'$ and we see how the mapping acts on the first component, which in this case is the same. But when it comes to the second component it can be either $e^y + e^{y'}$, if we consider component by component or $e^{y+y'}$ if we consider the whole component.

How we evaluate this, I guess the answer would apply also to proving homogeneity.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

x part is linear however y part is not. Consider this:

$$A(y)=e^y$$

$$A(y_1)+A(y_2)=e^{y_1}+e^{y_2}$$

$$A(y_1+y_2)=e^{y_1+y_2}$$

so clearly

$$A(y_1+y_2)\neq A(y_1)+A(y_2)$$

as a sanity check, I usually just compare what happens when I insert $2y$, it is best to do it the long way to be sure but if it doesn't work for $2y$, you can immediately rule out linearity.

$$e^{2y}\neq 2e^y$$

EDIT: I would also like to talk about something extra, because so many people get confused. What about this:

$$A(\ y(x)\ )=x^2y(x)$$

This is still linear.

$$A(\ y_1(x)\ )+A(\ y_2(x)\ )=x^2y_1(x)x^2y_2(x)=x^2(y_1(x)+y_2(x))$$

$$A(\ y_1(x)\ y_2(x)\ )=x^2(y_1(x)+y_2(x))$$

$$A(\ y_1(x)\ )+A(\ y_2(x)\ )=A(\ y_1(x)\ y_2(x)\ )$$

Answer (score 0):

$A(x,y)=(x,e^y)$ means you map the $x$ component of the vector to itself, $y$ component to $e^y$.

If your vector now is $(x+x',y+y')$, $A$ maps it to $(x+x', e^{y+y'})$ because $y+y'$ is the $y$ component of this whole vector.

It is then not linear.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is a linear map, then $A(\vec{0})=\vec{0}$ (by homogeneity). In your case,
$$
A(\vec{0})=A(0,0)=(0,e^0)=(0,1)\ne\vec{0}
$$
so you rule out linearity.

However, this is just a good shortcut in some cases; the map $B(x,y)=(x,y^2)$ satisfies $B(\vec{0})=\vec{0}$, but is not linear. Try with homogeneity with $\alpha=-1$ and $\vec{x}=(1,-1)$, showing that $B(\alpha\vec{x})\ne\alpha B(\vec{x})$.

In general, in order to show non linearity, you have to show a counterexample. The ones I used for $A$ and $B$ are sufficient. I suggest you to first attack with $\vec{0}$, then with homogeneity and only as a last weapon with additivity.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. When checking if a mapping is LINEAR, is it sufficient to only check if the zero vector maps to a zero vector? Does this apply to every case?

Comment: @user240751 No, it is *not* sufficient for checking linearity. It may be sufficient for checking *non* linearity.